# Добавление элементов Windows Form программно

Tags: c#, winforms

В принципе простые элементы добавления мне известны.
Типа:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox myText = new TextBox();
    myText.Location = new Point(25, 25);
    this.Controls.Add(myText);
}
```

Но как быть с автоматическим добавлением элементов. Вот у меня есть такой код:
Где я вручную добавил 18 элементов (Picture Box, и Label) поскольку это соответствует количеству спарсенных элементов списка.

И в цикле уже присваивал им значения.

```
public void MainCol()
{
    #region Boxes
    PictureBox[] boxes = {
    pictureBox1, pictureBox2, pictureBox3, pictureBox4, pictureBox5, pictureBox6, pictureBox7, pictureBox8,
                pictureBox9, pictureBox10, pictureBox11, pictureBox12, pictureBox13, pictureBox14, pictureBox15, pictureBox16, pictureBox17, pictureBox18};
    Label[] labels = {
    label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6, label7, label8, label9, label10, label11, label12, label13, label14, label15,
            label16, label17, label18};
    Label[] qal = {
                qual1, qual2, qual3, qual4, qual5, qual6, qual7, qual8, qual9, qual10, qual11, qual12, qual13, qual14, qual15, qual16, qual17, qual18};
    #endregion

    var parsing = namefilm.ProductlistItem();

    int i = 0;

    foreach (var pars in parsing)
    {
        labels[i].Text = parsing[i].NameFilm;
        boxes[i].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        boxes[i].LoadAsync(parsing[i].ImageURl);
        qal[i].Text = parsing[0].Quality;
        LogTex2.Text += parsing[i].NameFilm + "\r\n";
        LogTex2.Text += parsing[i].ImageURl + "\r\n";
        LogTex2.Text += parsing[i].Quality + "\r\n";
        i++;
    }
}
```

Выглядит это все дело вот так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но как сделать так, чтоб в созданный мной FlowLayoutPanel, добавлялась Panel а в эту панель уже добавлялся PictureBox, и Label в соответствии количества списка. А то сотню таких элементов добавлять будет уже не интересно. Благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Идешь в цикле по списку и создаешь нужные контролы, в чем проблема то?

Comment: Я делал seasonvar плеер, правда на WPF и использовал ListBox. Сразу выводил картинку, ссылку на фильм и номер сезона. Попробуй ListBox.

Comment: Если нужно добавлять одинаковые группы контролов - значит пора знакомиться с UserControl и создавать свои контролы. Не забудьте предусмотреть необходимые свойства или методы для заполнения и обновления данных кастомного контрола.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можее контролы добавлять динамически, вам не обяхательно создавать ваши картинки заранее. Вот пример

```
public class MyForm: Form
{
    FlowLayoutPanel _fpanel;
    public MyForm()
    {
        _fpanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        _fpanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

        this.Controls.Add(_fpanel);     
        this.Load+=OnLoad;
    }


    private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _fpanel.Controls.Clear();

        for(var i=0; i<10; i++)
        {           
            var pb = new PictureBox();
            pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
            pb.LoadAsync("url");
            _fpanel.Controls.Add(pb);           

        }
    }
}
```

Как видите, я тут просто прохожу циклом и добавляю в панель всё, что хочу. У меня картинки не загрузятся, потому мое окно будет выглядеть вот так

[image: Результат]

Comment: Отличный вариант спасибо, но есть проблема при добавлении свойства .Fill к flowLayoutPanel. Поскольку если какие то элементы формы были добавлены вручную..например ТекстБокс, то flowLayoutPanel оказывается на заднем плане, за Текстбоксом и не совсем корректно отображается.

Comment: Проблема решилась путем добавления в основную форму сделанного вручную 'this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);' И уже на него вешать 'flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pn); pn.Controls.Add(pb); pn.Controls.Add(lb);'

Comment: @SaDLiF это пример как динамически всю форму собрать. Вам же всю форму собирать в динамике не обязательно. Создайте форму, накидайте панели как вам хочется в дизайнере, а динамически только данные в панельку закидывайте и всё дела

Answer (score 1):

Собственно вот такой получился код:

```
        public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        ParserHTML parserHTML = new ParserHTML();
        NameFilm namefilm = new NameFilm();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ParserHTML parserHTML = new ParserHTML();
            LogText.Text = parserHTML.LoadPage();
            this.Controls.Add(flowLayoutPanel1);
            this.Load += OnLoad;

        }
        private void OnLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var parsing = namefilm.ProductlistItem();

            int i = 0;

            foreach (var pars in parsing)
                {
                var pn = new Panel();
                pn.Size = new Size(140, 180);
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(pn);
                ;
                var pb = new PictureBox();
                pb.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                pb.Size = new Size(140, 140);
                pb.LoadAsync(parsing[i].ImageURl);
                pn.Controls.Add(pb);

                var lb = new Label();
                lb.Text = parsing[i].NameFilm;
                lb.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
                pn.Controls.Add(lb);
                i++;
                }
            }
    }
```

Не идеальный, но для теста подойдет, результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]